# Save Date and the Hour from Swift to a Firestore Document

Tags: swift, date, google-cloud-firestore

How can I save a `date` from swift with the current `hour` from my app into the Firestore document?

```
let todayDateAndHour = Date()
```

This is the data I am trying to save to Firestore:

```
let data : [String: Any] = [
"DateAndHour" : todayDateAndHour
]
```

I send this data to CloudFunctions with this call:

```
Functions.functions().httpsCallable("saveDate").call(data) {
}
```

Then in Cloud Function I do the following:

```
exports.saveDate = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
const cloudDateAndHour = data.DateAndHour

return db.collection('MyCollection').doc('MyDocument').set({
timeStampDateAndHour: cloudDateAndHour
})

}
```

I know my cloud funcitons work but the date I believe I need to convert it to another format in swift so it can be saved in firestore? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to save the date as a `String`?  You can use `DateFormatter` for that, and your implementation might look something like this:

```
let todayDateAndHour = Date()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hhZ"
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: todayDateAndHour) //"2019-12-20 02-0800"

let data : [String: Any] = ["DateAndHour" : dateString]
```

That said, Firestore also supports `Date`s, so this is really just based on your preference.  Check [their docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) for details.

Later on if you wanted to turn these strings back into `Date`s you can do so with the same formatter like so:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hhZ"
let fullDate: Date? = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

Please note that (as I indicated here) that `DateFormatter.date(from: String)` return an `Optional<Date>` for the obvious reason that you could pass any random `String` into the method.  You will also need to make sure that the `DateFormatter.dateFormat` is the same going in as it is coming out.

Comment: If I save it as string; later on when I want to use this date from firestore and sort my results on my app based on the date/hour, would I be able to achieve that using the string data? Or that requires me to save the date with Timestamp format?